# How do I reference a dll from SSIS in 2012?

Tags: ssis, dll-reference

I am trying to add a dll reference to my SSIS package (2012) with a script Component. The IntelliSense is working for me and I don't see error when coding. However, I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'XYZ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XYZ' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a custom DLL, then you will need to install it into the GAC (global assembly cache) for it to run outside of SSDT.

An assembly cannot be installed into the GAC unless it's [strongly signed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx). Once it's signed, from a Visual Studio command prompt, registration would look like `gacutil -if MyRadAssembly.dll`