# SSIS with assemblies

Tags: ssis, assemblies

In the previous server envirement I was using assmeblies with stored procedures. But in the new envirement its not allowed anymore to use this kind of assemblies. they told me I have to do that in SSIS.

my question is: I have a c# code and I made a *.dll file out of it witch is supposed to put into the assembly. how can I use this *.dll file with SSIS that it does the same like it done before? I realy haven't any idea how this should work.

additinal infos
the db is in a cluster and the application server is in a VM. i cant connect to the db.
using `gacutil -i <assembly name>` doesen't work :(

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104830/how-do-i-reference-a-dll-from-ssis-in-2012/11107481#11107481

Comment: okey. Im using 2008 R2 server. I cant install gac on this cluster. as well as I dont have the permission to do that or even they are as well not allowed to do it.

Comment: Your version of SQL Server is irrelevant. If you can't push an assembly into the GAC, you won't be able to reference it within an SSIS script task.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to describe the types of problems you were classically solving with your custom assemblies. There may be native SSIS capabilities to do the same thing

Comment: maybe now is my problem little bit mor understanable?

Comment: Not really. What problem are your assemblies solving?